# Kendo UI datepicker value disappear after server filtering in kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, datepicker, kendo-grid, kendo-datepicker

I am using Kendo Grid and filterable mode row. One of the columns is using a kendoDatePicker.

I filter on server and my problem is, when I pick a value on the datePicker, filtering works fine, but when it shows the data, the value doesn't stay in filter input, it disappears.

I am using to set the DatePicker:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/kukatko/search",
                    dataType: "json",
                    cache: false
                },
                parameterMap: function (data, type) {
                    if (type == "read") {
                        var paramMap = kendo.data.transports.odata.parameterMap(data.filter);
                        return paramMap;
                    }
                }
            },
            serverFiltering: true,
            pageSize: 10
        },
        filterable: {
            mode: "row"
        },
        sortable: true,
        pageable: true,
        reorderable: true,
        columns: [{...(some other columns)...
        }, {
            field: "datumZalozenia",
            title: "Dátum založenia",
            width: "150px",
            parseFormats: ["d.M.yyyy"],
            format: "d.M.yyyy",
            template: "#=kendo.toString(new Date(datumZalozenia), 'd')#",
            filterable: {
                cell: {
                    showOperators: false,
                    operator: "contains",
                    format: "{0:d.M.yyyy}",
                    template: function (args) {
                        args.element.kendoDatePicker({
                            format: "d.M.yyyy"
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
```

Here is an image of how it looks (before, select value and after):

[image]

I selected 15.7.2015 so filtering on server runs without any problems.